# How to change the background color of react-bootstrap's switch (part of the Forms component) using Emotion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, emotion

How do you update the default blue background color of the [switch found in react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-custom-switch) (not react-bootstrap-switch) using Emotion?

When I go into Chrome's devtools I'm able to make the change but can't seem to get it right on the React side.

**from devtools**

[image]
[image]

**my attempt**

```
<Form>
  <Form.Switch
    id="custom-switch"
    label="text goes here"
    bsCustomPrefix={`custom-control-input:checked~custom-control-label::before ${css`background: red;`}`}
  />
</Form>
```

I've also tried using `className` in lieu of `bsCustomPrefix`.

**what actually happens**

[image]

the entire item gets altered.

Comment: Please provide the minimum reproducible code.

Comment: Did you try doing with CSS directly?

Answer (score 3):

CSS :

```
.custom-control-label::before {
    background-color: #28a745;
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-label::after {
    background-color: white;
}

.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
    background-color: red;
}
```

For :

```
  function Toggle(props) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
    return (
        <Form.Check
            onClick={() => setShow(!show)}
            type="switch"
            id="custom-switch"
            label={show ? 'Text1' : 'Text2'}
        />
    );
   }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my index.css I added a boostrap override section. You can give the switch a specific class or override all of them (I overrode all of them since it was for light/dark color change)

```css
.form-check-input {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%27http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%27 viewBox=%27-4 -4 8 8%27><circle r=%273%27 fill=%27%23666%27/></svg>") !important;
}
.form-check-input:checked {
  background-color: #666 !important;
  border-color: #6668 !important;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%27http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%27 viewBox=%27-4 -4 8 8%27><circle r=%273%27 fill=%27%23fff%27/></svg>") !important;
}

.form-check-input:focus {
  border-color: #6668 !important;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I incurred a similar task at hand.
So I managed to pull off the feat with attribute selector (Took a hint from their implementation).
So in StyleSheet I wrote this,

```
[class='custom-control-input']:checked ~ [class='custom-control-label']::before {
       
        background-color: hotpink; //Example Code

}
```

Comment: How to make this work based on react-bootstrap variant?

Comment: @pranaynailwal Do you know how to change the color of the handle (the circle indicator)?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure since there's no code example, have you tried something like this:

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

<Form>
  <CustomSwitch
    id="custom-switch"
    label="text goes here"
    bsCustomPrefix={`custom-control-input:checked~custom-control-label::before`}
  />
</Form>

const CustomSwitch = styled(Form.Switch)`
  &::before {
    background: red
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off off Pranay Nailwal.. but something simpler.

Assuming the necssary files have been installed to support switches.
`npm i react-bootstrap@2.0.0 bootstrap@5.1.3`

```
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form"
...
<Form.Switch id="mySwitch"/>
...
```

*css File*

```
#mySwitch{
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3e%3ccircle r='3' fill='%23fff'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  background-color: #28a745;
}
#mySwitch:checked{
  background-color: red;
}
```

You will need to update the image attribute if you want the SVG node in the button to be white. On "unchecked" the svg react-botostrap uses is transparent.